# QT REST development for HTML web client on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, rest, real-time

In the Linux system we need to stream data as JSON format for real time data communication. for example we are tuning volume through web client than it should post to server and vice versa. 
  What could be best way to build rest development with QT which is communicating the other module too.

Comment: Slyps i will do as you said .actually im looking  for some good examples because im completely new to this HTTP server . im a Qt Gui developer earlier and have no knowledge in HTTP

Comment: also i want to know How to do routing using HTTPs.

Comment: https://github.com/supamii/QttpServer is QttpServer for a Qt based Http server that supports RESTish ideas in the sense that theres support for JSON, API routes, and most importantly Qt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been added direct support of JSON in Qt 5. Check available classes [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/json.html).

To communicate with web part you should use [QNetworkManagerAccess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) class.

Here it's example of how it can be implemented (not tested):

```
QVariantMap top;
top.insert( "key1", QString( "value1" ) );
top.insert( "key2", QString( "value2" ) );
const QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(top);
QByteArray postData = doc.toJson();

QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

QNetworkRequest req;
req.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.test.com"));
req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");

QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(req,postData);
...
```

Comment: Hi can you give me small sample project source code for handling HTTP request response like real time streaming.

Comment: @Wagmare, sorry, don't have such, but I believe you can pretty quick made it yourself now.

Comment: I am just wondering for one part that how will do routing in web server for client request for navigating the request to specific function/handler.